# RSpec allow_any_instance_of does not work within request test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to RSpec, and testing out some webhook test with request type.
But here even I use `allow_any_instance_of`, it errors out `got 500 instead of 200`. I checked every variable with `binding.pry` but it seems all okay.
In my opinion, the mocking fails so it returns `500`.
Any ideas?

```
describe "stripe_invoice_created_webhook", type: :request do

  let(:card_invoice){ create(:card_invoice, id: invoice.id) }
  let(:invoice){ create(:invoice, payment_account_id: payment_card_account.payment_account_id) }
  let(:payment_card_account){ create(:payment_card_account,
                                     stripe_customer_id: event.data.object.customer) }
  let(:event){ StripeMock.mock_webhook_event('invoice.created', {
    closed: false
  }) }

  it 'responds 200 to invoice_created webhook with valid endpoint' do
    allow_any_instance_of(CardInvoice).to receive(:process_invoice_items)
    allow_any_instance_of(CardInvoice).to receive(:process!)

    post '/stripe-events', event.as_json
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
    expect{ card_invoice.process_invoice_items }.not_to raise_error
    expect{ card_invoice.process! }.not_to raise_error
  end
```

and the original code is

```
class InvoiceCreated
  def call(event)
    invoice = event.data.object

    # NOTE: Skip if the invoice is closed.
    if invoice.closed == false
      stripe_customer = invoice.customer
      payment_account = PaymentCardAccount.find_by(stripe_customer_id: stripe_customer)
      card_invoice = Invoice.find_card_invoice_in_this_month_within(payment_account: payment_account)

      card_invoice.process_invoice_items(stripe_customer: stripe_customer,
                                         event_invoice_id: invoice.id)
      card_invoice.process!(:pending, id: invoice.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the mocking fails. You are expecting the object CardVoice to receive process! or process_invoice_item but you have notnta specified a return value. The syntax for allow_any_instance_of is

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:function).and_return(:return_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but .and_return(true) doesn't work. Why is that?